# String manipulation in a SQL result set

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, substring

Im currently studying sql statements and got curious of this specific exercise in the net.
the problem is 
"*How can I encrypt every letter in a row that contain two or more spaces?( **with spaces not included**)*"
I have created a sample table here

```
         sample
-----------------------
first
first second
first second third
first second third fourth
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
         sample
-----------------------
first
first second
first ****** *****
first ****** ***** fourth
```

and this is what I've tried so far:

```
select name, substring(name, E'(\\s\\w+\\s.*)') from sample ;
```

Comment: I could give you a simple t-sql solution if you are interested

Comment: I haven't read about t-sql before, but if you could give me some ideas regarding my question I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is too complicated to do it in simple select so I used function with rich PostgreSQL string functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hide_middle(s varchar)
    RETURNS varchar AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r varchar;
    arr  varchar[];
BEGIN
    r := s;
    arr := regexp_matches(s, '^(\\S+ )(.*)( \\S+)$');
    IF array_length(arr, 1) = 3 THEN
        r := arr[1] || regexp_replace(arr[2], '\\S', '*', 'g') || arr[3];
    END IF;
    RETURN r;
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

You can use it with:

```
select hide_middle('first second third fourth')
```

Comment: I'm still learning postgresql, so I would like it to be in a select statement only, havent read the function part yet. But thanks for the answer, I will look up to it when I go to Postgresql function.

Comment: Functions are very useful and PostgreSQL is known from wide range of languages. There you see PL/PGSQL, but you can use Perl, Python (my favorite), Java etc. In my solution I use `\\S+` which means: "not white character once or more", but if you data is with tabs or new lines you can change it into `[^ ]+` which means "all characters without space, once or more".